# Using scopes and checkboxes to filter index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filtering

Like many questions here on SO, I'm attempting to build a form where checkboxes filter my index view. This would ideally occur with AJAX so I don't reload anything. The problem is that I'm as much of a beginner to Rails and programming as can be so I need help on how to set this up.

The index I want to filter is /users, where the values of the checkboxes are attached to the current_user's profile. For example, consider the following:

```
<% form_for(current_user.profile) do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.current_city %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :current_city %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.hometown %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :hometown %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If this worked properly with my model and database, clicking either or both of the checkboxes would render the appropriate profiles in my index partial.

I believe I need to use scopes but don't know to do that with so many profile attributes.

**UsersController:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @user = User.all
    @profile = Profile.all
  end
end
```

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Profile model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I've looked at [MetaSearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) but I want to learn how to do it without a gem for the moment.

Comment: First of all use MetaSearch. If you just trying to learn language, then read meta_search sources, also read asciicasts, there are a answers on your questions. Also don't forget to use attr_accessible. Learn some metaprogramming, it might help you to do things easier than you think. Also write tests/specs for everything you do, before you do anything actually. Then you will understand how to write good and usable APIs and you start to understand how to write code better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, I think the answer to this question is going to be very similar to the answer on your related question, [How to make parts of Profile searchable or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883869/how-to-make-parts-of-profile-searchable-or-not/7903033#7903033)

Basically, you need to tie the check boxes to the setting of either per-column visibility flags, or the creation/destruction of visibility records, depending on how fine-grained your access rights need to be.

That is, checking a check box should set the appropriate visibility flag/record for that user (you can do that via AJAX), and un-checking it will clear/destroy the appropriate visibility flag/record.

IF, on the other hand, the form you're talking is a global, "What partials do I render for my user index page?" kind of form that an admin is editing, then setup a table called whatever you want (`partial_renderings`?) that contains boolean columns, one for each partial, that get set/cleared when check boxes are checked/un-checked.

Then, the if statement around a partial rendering is something like:

```
...
<% if PartalRenderings.show_hometown %>
  <%= render :partial => "user_hometown", :locals => {:user => @user}
<% end %>
...
```

The `partial_renderings` table would probably just have a single record, since it's just a set of flags.

Then the `PartialRenderings` model would basically be empty, because all you'll be doing is checking boolean values.

Finally, the `partial_renderings` table could be structured like this:

```
id | show_hometown | show_phone_number | show_real_name | ...etc...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | true          | false             | false          | ...
```

If partial rendering is on a PER-USER basis, then the `partial_renderings` table would need an additional `user_id` field to tie it to a given user, and therefore allow users to decide which things get rendered, and which don't. In this case you'd have more than a single record - you'd have one per user.