# How to make parts of Profile searchable or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app, I want to allow a user to specify which parts of their profile can be searchable by others. I know how to do this if I wanted to make the entire user invisible, but how can I set it up so multiple fields can be designated searchable or not separately?

**More info:**

In terms of functionality, I want to limit searches based on what parts of their profile a user chooses to be searchable in `/settings`. Parts of the profile would be, for example, `@user.profile.hometown` or `@user.profile.current_city`. I'm working off of a Combination of [Railscasts #52](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) and [Trevor Turk's tutorial](http://trevorturk.com/2010/08/24/easy-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/) to set what others can search through checkboxes in the settings.

When searchability is defined in settings, when a user searches (or filters) the `/users` index, what isn't hidden will be public and searchable. In terms of how this works in the DB as far as hiding table columns or grouping, I thought about hiding tables but maybe that's not the best solution. I'm as beginner as can be and hadn't really thought much about that to be honest.

Comment: Info added to the question! I'll delete my comments now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Method 1 - show/hide specific columns

So, the most direct way (and this will work if there are only a handful of things you want to show/hide), is just to create a boolean column for every thing you need to show/hide. So, if you had a phone number field, you could have a column called "show_phone_number", and when true it would show it.

## Method 2 - show/hide whole sections

The next level that you might need is, rather than showing/hiding particular columns, have your show/hide boolean columns something like `show_contact_info`, `show_photos`, etc. for each logical section that a user would show or hide.

Then in your view, you'd have something like:

`app/views/user/show.html.erb` (or `.haml` or whatever you're using)

```
....
<% if @user.show_contact_info %>
  <%= render :partial => "user_contact_info", :locals => {:user => @user} %>
<% end %>
```

`app/views/partials/_user_contact_info.html.erb`

```
<%=h user.email %><br />
<%=h user.phone_number %><br />
<%=  user.blog_url %><br />
...
```

## Method 3 - show/hide sections based on who is viewing it

Finally (and the code here is untested, but I think you'll get the idea) let's say your site has a social structure, and you want to show information to some people, but not to others. Basically you'll need the following in some form or another:

- Section visibilities (who can view what sections)
- Roles (friends, followers, public, private)
- a few methods to make these relationships clear/easy to understand

So, in your `User` model you'd have something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends, :through => "friendships"  # or whatever construct you have
  has_many :followers, :through => "followings" # or whatever construct you have
  has_many :profile_visibilities
  ...

  def is_friends_with(user)
    friends.include?(user)
  end

  def is_a_follower_of(user)
    user.followers.include?(self)
  end

  def can_see(visibilities)
    visibilities.each do |v|
      v.user == self || v.is_public || can_see_because_we_are_friends(v) || can_see_because_i_follow(v)
    end
  end

  private:
  def can_see_because_we_are_friends(visibility)
    visibility.is_friend && is_friends_with(visibility.user)
  end

  def can_see_because_i_follow(visibility)
    visibility.is_follower && is_follower_of(visibility.user)
  end
end
```

Then a class called `ProfileVisibilities`:

```
class  ProfileVisibilities < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...

  def is_public
    visibility == "public"
  end

  def is_friend
    visibility == "friends"
  end

  def is_follower
    visibility == "followers"

  def is_private
    !is_public && !is_friend && !is_follower
  end
end
```

Then a table called `profile_visibilities`

```
id  | user_id | profile_section | visibility
----------------------------------------------
1   | 1       | contact_info    | public        # <= visible to everyone
2   | 1       | personal_info   | friends       # <= visible only to "friends"
3   | 1       | blog_posts      | friends       # <= visible to "friends"
4   | 1       | blog_posts      | followers     # <= ...and followers
5   | 1       | photos          | friends       # <= visible only to "friends"
```

Then in your controller, something like:

`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`

```
...
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @contact_info_visibilities = ProfileVisibilities.find(:all, :conditions = ['user_id = ? AND profile_section = "contact_info"', @user.id]
  @photo_visibilities = ProfileVisibilities.find(:all, :conditions = ['user_id = ? AND profile_section = "photos"', @user.id]
  # ... and more for each section visibility you need
end
...
```

And in your view:

`app/views/user/show.html.erb`

```
...
<% if current_user.can_see(@contact_info_visibilities) %>
  <%= render :partial => "user_contact_info", :locals => {:user => @user}
<% end %>

<% if current_user.can_see(@photo_visibilities) %>
  <%= render :partial => "user_photos", :locals => {:user => @user}
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: Wow, loads to digest. Thanks so very much!